# Correct Iteration with deletion in List syntax

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing a program that uses lists at a point in said program i want to iterate through 3 three lists a, b and c, and delete any element in b and c if it appears in a. Im doing it as such:

```
//remove elements from OpenList that are in ClosedList
    for(list<Node> :: iterator cloIt = ClosedList.begin(); cloIt != ClosedList.end(); cloIt++)
    {
        for(list<Node> :: iterator opIt = OpenList.begin(); opIt != OpenList.end(); opIt++)
        {
            for(list<Node> :: iterator neigIt = Neighbour.begin(); neigIt != Neighbour.end(); neigIt++)
            {
                if (*cloIt == *opIt)
                {
                    opIt = OpenList.erase(opIt);

                }
                if (*cloIt == *neigIt)
                {
                    neigIt = Neighbour.erase(neigIt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However this is causing me to get an "List iterator not incrementable" error
How could i fix this?

Comment: Erasing an element invalidates all iterators that point to it. You have to do the (save; increment; erase-saved) sequence.

Comment: @n.m.: No, that's for maps. List erase gives you the next iterator.

Answer (score 1):

From your erase call, you want to

> 1. remove OpenList items if they are found in ClosedList list
> 2. remove Neighbour items if they are found from ClosedListlist

You'd better separate code into two loops, instead of nested loops, for example:

**1.remove OpenList items if they are found in ClosedList list**

```
for(auto cloIt = ClosedList.begin(); cloIt != ClosedList.end(); ++cloIt)
{
   OpenList.remove_if([&](const Node& n){ return n == *colIt; } );
}
```

**2.remove Neighbour items if they are found from ClosedListlist**

```
for(auto cloIt = ClosedList.begin(); cloIt != ClosedList.end(); ++cloIt)
{
   Neighbour.remove_if([&](const Node& n){ return n == *colIt; } );
}
```

Obvious previous code is duplicated, you could write a common function for that:

```
void RemoveItem(std::list<Node>& node_list, std::list<Node>& node_list2)
{
   for(auto cloIt = node_list2.begin(); cloIt != node_list2.end(); ++cloIt)
   {
      node_list.remove_if([&](const Node& n){ return n == *colIt; } );
   }
}
```

Now you could call:

```
RemoveItem(OpenList, CloseList);
RemoveItem(Neighbour, CloseList);
```

**Update:**
Don't forget to define operator== for Node type, for example if node has getId interface:

```
bool operator==(const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs)
{
  return lhs.getId() == rhs.getId();
}
```

Comment: Tried it, i got this error

"IntelliSense: an enclosing-function local variable cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list"

Comment: Sorry @WillzSawyer, I forgot lambda capture `&`, I've updated my code.

Comment: says that there is no == operator, im sorry if im being stupid im just really tired

Comment: you need to define operator== function for Node type, see my updated answer.

Comment: Although i solved the problem now, your method is most certainly the most interesting and promising. I ended up using @Lightness's solution but I'd really like to use yours, I was getting an error where C++ wouldnt except a == operator with two input...Also you are the nicest person ive ever seen on stack overflow :) Thank you again and again

Answer (score 0):

> How could i fix this?

The best way is to use standard algorithms and let them do the iteration, search, and/or the conditional removal for you.

You could use `std::list`'s [`remove_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) member function with a lambda predicate that checks if the element is contained in list `a`:

```
#include <algorithm>

// ...

b.remove_if(
    [&a] (Node const& n)
    {
        return (std::find(begin(a), end(a), n) != a.end());
    });
```

Same for removing elements from `c` if they are contained in `a`.

Another possibility is to use `std::for_each()` to iterate over all elements of `a` and remove them from `b` and `c`:

```
#include <algorithm>

// ...

std::for_each(begin(a), end(a),
    [&b, &c] (Node const& n)
    {
        b.remove(n);
        c.remove(n);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, when I try to use the first one std::find apparently doesnt exist :S i made sure that i put #include< algorithm >

EDIT: I've been replaceing a and b in your example with the appropriate list name...is that correct or should this be a method?

Comment: @WillzSawyer: Not sure I understand what you mean. You did `#include <algorithm>` and you get a compilation error saying that `std::find` doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

You've correctly used the return value of `.erase` to obtain the new iterator, but forgot that this iterator gets `++`'d immediately at the end of the current iteration of your loop; if the result of `.erase` was `.end`, then this is an invalid operation.

(You're actually very fortunate that you get a diagnostic for attempting to increment your now-invalid iterators — the standard guarantees absolutely nothing about this case.)

**You need to `++` *only* when you didn't `.erase`.**

The general pattern looks like this:

```
for (typename list<T>::iterator it = l.begin(), end = l.end(); it != end; )
{
    // ^^ NB. no "it++" in the loop introduction!

    if (foo(*it)) {
       // condition satisfied; do the erase, and get the next
       // iterator from `.erase` and NOT through incrementing
       it = l.erase(it);
    }
    else {
       // no erasure; do the increment only in this case
       it++;
    }
}
```

You could avoid the problem altogether by using standard algorithms, as Andy suggests.